# getting model object returned matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I want to display what user is posted from a `Book` model when others user visited his public_profile page, to do that, i had to use this method:

```
def public_profile(request, slug):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, slug=slug)
    book = Book.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'book': book
    }
    return render(request, 'public_profile.html', context)
```

But using that method returned: `Book matching query does not exist.` in the `public_profile` template.

my url to `public_profile` page:

```
<p class="title is-4"><a href="{{ book.get_user_public_url }}">
     {{ book.user }}
</a></p>
```

my model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='audio-image')
    introduction = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def get_user_public_url(self):
        return reverse('Public-Profile', kwargs={'slug': self.user.profile.slug})

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-image', default='static/dafault.jpg')
    twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    linkedln = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True,)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=700, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Comment: You need to debug what you are getting in "slug" and database records against that slug you have in the database.

Comment: You are retrieving both a `Profile` and `Book`, for the same slug, likely the book has not the same slug as the profile?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree with what you have said, but how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe.: well *what* do you try to do? The `get_user_public_url` is strange: it returns a link to a profile (not a book page), with the slug of the user profile?

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe.: extactly what is `book` supposed to be? It is not said that the profile has any book, and it is also possible that it has *multiple* books.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem exactly using this method `get_user_public_url` can only return `Profile` object not `Book` model, but how can I change the `url` to display `Profile` object and `Book` object when user clicked on `username` from a post model?

Comment: @Bamagujen_Bahaushe.: but *what* book, there can be *no* books, one book, or *multiple* books related to the same profile.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem take at `Stack Overflow` as an example, when someone asked questions, you and me can visited his profile page, and you and me can see his profile photo, username, Location, and and all the questions he asked in `Stack Overflow `, so I want to implement something like that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem take a look at the answer down below: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76045872/19420551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I'm trying to get the `Book` object using `slug=slug`, which is the same argument used to retrieve the `Profile` object. However, `slug` is a unique field for the Book object, so I'm actually trying to retrieve the Book object using the wrong field.

To fix this, I try to do that using the method below:

```
def public_profile(request, slug):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, slug=slug)
    book = Book.objects.get(user=profile.user)
    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'book': book
    }
    return render(request, 'public_profile.html', context)
```

But I get this error: `get return more than one Book --it returned 2!` because @WillemVanOnsem in the comment section said: `what is book supposed to be? It is not said that the profile has any book, and it is also possible that it has multiple books.` meaning that: there are two or more Book objects in my database that have the same user value as the User object associated with the Profile object I'm trying to retrieve.

So, I changed my code into this:

```
def public_profile(request, slug):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, slug=slug)
    books = Book.objects.filter(user=profile.user)
    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'books': books
    }
    return render(request, 'public_profile.html', context)
```

And get `Book` for that user using:

```
{% for book in books %}
    <p class="title is-4">
        {{ book.title }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```